# Thread order execution?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, clr

I have this simple code  : (*which i run in linqpad*)

```
void Main()
{
    for ( int  i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
      int  tmp=i;
      new Thread (() =>doWork(tmp)).Start();
     }
}

 public void doWork( int h)
 {
 h.Dump();
 }
```

the `int  tmp=i;` line is for capture variable  - so each iteration will have its own value.

2 problems :

**1)** the numbers are *not* sequential , while thread execution is !

**2)** sometimes i get *less* than 10 numbers !

here are some executions outputs:

[image][image][image][image]

**questions** :

1) why case 1 is happening and how can i solve it ?

2) why case 2 is happening and how can i solve it ?

Comment: 2 is easy -- don't terminate your program until it's finished doing all the work it needs to do. (Returning from `main` terminates your program.) I don't follow your issue with 1 -- nothing in your code makes any effort to make them sequential, and if you want them to be sequential, why dispatch them to threads?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yep.... what about 1 ?

Comment: If you want to do tasks sequentially, why do you dispatch them to different threads?!

Comment: 1 is easy, too: threads are starting slowly with unpredictable delay, so the order of their actual start is undefined. You have to wait for (i-1)'th thread to finish before starting the work in nth one -- which however defeats the whole purpose of multithreading

Comment: the main point of using threads to get concurrency, I think you shouldn't use threads in your task if you want to get sequential output. But if you need sequental output with threads in this task use Join() : var t = new Thread (() =>doWork(tmp)).Start(); t.Join();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should not be expected that they are sequential. Each thread gets priority **as the kernel chooses**. It might **happen** that they look sequential, purely by the nature of when each is started, but that is pure chance.

For ensuring that they all complete - mark each new thread as `IsBackground = false`, so that it keeps the executable alive. For example:

```
new Thread(() => doWork(tmp)) { IsBackground = false }.Start();
```

Comment: If order is important, execute them in order. If order is not important, dispatch them to a bunch of threads.

Comment: @Royi: for learning, I would recommend this: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Signaling_with_Event_Wait_Handles

Comment: Is the definition of "Thread" clear to you? Threads are supposed to be executed *in parallel*.

Comment: @RoyiNamir the whole point of parallelism is to do things *at the same time*. Which is **not ordered**. Also: note that in most *real* uses of threading, you wouldn't create a `Thread` for a small unit of work like this. Use the `ThreadPool`, or the TPL in 4.0

Comment: @Royi: `Sleep` doesn't guarantee anything: the kernel may block the thread for some indefinite time if it wants to.

Comment: @vlad look at my profile - info image - second book from top. ( thats what im reading). ( the same author....)

Comment: @Royi: nice book list! You are on the right way. (My URL was pointing to an excerpt from the book you are reading.)

Comment: @MarcGravell IMHO backgoround threads arent keeping the main thread alive , they just ensuring to die when main thread dies....no ?

Comment: @Royi: non-background threads outlive the main procedure, whereas background threads die when `Main` exits.

Answer (score 2):

Threads execute in unpredictable order, and if the main thread finishes before others you'll not get all the numbers (dump() will not execute). If you mark your threads as IsBackground = false you'll get them all. There's no real solution for the first one except not using threads (or joining threads, which is same thing really).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't expect any ordering between threads.

If you start a new thread, it is merely added to the operating system's management structures. Eventually the thread scheduler will come around and allocate a time slice for the thread. It may do this in a round-robin fashion, pick a random one, use some heuristics to determine which one looks most important (eg. one that owns a Window which is in the foreground) and so on.

If the order of the outputs is relevant, you can either sort it afterwards or - if you know the ordering before work begins already - use an array where each thread is given an index into which it should write its result.

Creating new threads the way your example does is also very slow. For micro tasks, using the thread pool is at least one order of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of thread management is random. You can solve both task, but overhead is too big.

1. Problem appears that multiple thread concurs on console (or what you use for dump), overriding of sync mechanism is possible but complicated and will cause reduce of performance
2. You exit before all threads are invoked (see answer by @Marc Gravell)

Answer (score 0):

if ordering is important you may want to avail of a shared queue and use a semaphore to ensure only one thread operates on the top of the queue at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can order thread execution, but it has to be done specifically by you for the specific problem with a specific solution.

> E.g.: you would like that thread 1,2,3 complete phase 1 of your code,
>   and then they proceed to the next phase in the order of their IDs (these IDs you have assign).

You can use **semaphores** to achieve the behavior - search for block synchronization and mutual exclusion and Test-and-set method.