# Methods execution order

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll

There are many classes A, B, C and so on.
In each of them, there are some methods:

```
class A {  
   void a1() { ...; }
   void a2() { ...; }
}
class B {  //dll
   void b1() { ...; }
   void b2() { ...; }
}
class C {  //dll
   void c1() { ...; }
   void c2() { ...; }
}
```

Class A is coded by me and the Class B and C are an imported dll.

With Class A I can put breakpoints to track, but I can't with Class B anc C.
My program is going to be of hundreds of classes and I'd like to track in what sequential order
methods in each class are called.
Is it possible to output this kind of information even there are methods defined in dll?

Ex. a1 -> b2 -> c1 -> a2

Added:
Especially when a dll method call another dll method.
In this case wrapper would be little help.
Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

If the code comes to you in a DLL with no source or debug symbols, your debug options are rather limited: you cannot set breakpoints with no source, unless you are comfortable looking at disassembly.

One way to address the issue is to wrap the external code in your own class, like this:

```
class CWrap {
    private readonly C wrapped = new C();
    public void c1() {
        log.Info("Entering c1");
        wrapped.c1();
        log.Info("Entering c1");
    }
    public void c2() {
        log.Info("Entering c2");
        wrapped.c2();
        log.Info("Exiting c2");
    }
}
```

Comment: the only issue with this approach is to make sure all original C's methods get replaced with wrapped ones. When C has thousands of methods it could be a nightmare.

Comment: @Chris When `C` has more than, say, 20 methods, I would write a simple reflection-based program to write the wrapper for me: enumerate through the methods, and print out the wrappers for them into a text file. Edit the file as needed, save as CS file, and compile.

Comment: if there is another dll "D" which calls methods in "C" the wrapper would do little help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mutltithreading is applied to Methods, not Classes.
2. Once you start the threads, order is indeterminate. [Thread order execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832702/thread-order-execution)

   ```
   var a = new A();  
   var b = new B();  
   var c = new C();

   new Thread(a.a1).Start();
   new Thread(b.b1).Start();
   new Thread(c.c1).Start();
   ```

   There is no definite order for a1, b1, c1.
3. If you like you can pipeline the execution using Tasks .

   ```
   Tasks.StartNew(()=> a.a1()).ContinueWith(_ => b.b1().ContinueWith(_=>c.c1);
   ```

   It pipelines execution of a1, b1 and c1.

   It makes use of [Tasks.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx)

> Is it possible to output this kind of information even there are methods defined in dll?

Yes, if you specify [debug build](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/02/14/difference-between-debug-vs-release-build.aspx)

Comment: multi-thread is not the issue here. just want to spit out the execution order.