# choosing the order of prints in pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have some threads working on an array, and each of them sorts their part, in parallel with the others. I have a global array of pthread_t, in which i sort the id of each thread. Here is the part I can't figure out: After a thread is done with sorting I want it to print something, but the order must be from threads[MAX] to threads[0]. How do I do this? I tried to understand how to use pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_signal() but I'm not even sure if this is what I need to do my job.

Essentially what I want is, my threads to work in parallel until they reach to a specific point, in which I want them to continue in a specific order.

Comment: Print the data after all the threads have finished? it can't be done in parallel.

Comment: @WeatherVane first of all, I dont want to print in parallel but in a specific order, and second of all I dont want to print **after** they are finished, but the print is in the last line of each thread.

Comment: Why does the print have to be the last line of each thread?

Comment: 'my threads to work in parallel' fine... 'in which I want them to continue in a specific order' un-fine.  Try to design away any kind of kind of dependecy like that - it's a really nasty plan.  If you just need what you say in the first para, just do as @WeatherVane suggests:)

Comment: 'but the print is in the last line of each thread' ugh - change your design.

Comment: @ScottHunter well it doesnt have to be, i just mean i dont need to do anything else after printing

Comment: @ThingyWotsit i know its pointless to print in a specific order, i just have to do it

Comment: Pesuading your threads to run in some defined order is worse than herding cats.  It's more like herding exploding cougars.  You are adding a large amount of unnecessary gunge to what should be a reasonably simple task.  I can't see how any such exercise would be of much use to future SO users:(

Comment: If you really want to print from each thread in reverse order, it must wait until thread+1 has printed, except the last thread, which you say is `threads[MAX]` but I suspect is `threads[MAX-1]`.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit telling me "dont do it like this" is not much help. Im trying to figure out how to do it, I'm not looking for an alternative. As I already said I know it's stupid, but that's what the project asks and that's what I must do.

Comment: @WeatherVane that is what i tried to do. `pthread_join(threads[i+1], NULL)` but it doesnt seem to work all the time. My guess is that threads[i+1] was not yet initialized, and with a default value of 0 the `join` did nothing.

Comment: ..and the mess gets eve deeper:((   OK, if you must try this, (yes, we know it's an assignment dreamt up by your prof/TA), can you not just create the threads from the top down?   In your loop, create threads[MAX-1] first and work down?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread order execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832702/thread-order-execution)

Comment: @ThingyWotsit so you mean I should create the `max-1`-th thread first, and in combination with using `join` there cannot be any problem? I will try this

Comment: @Sneftel I dont think it's a duplicate, at all. What I'm asking is "How do I force the threads to continue running in a specific order after a specific point?".

Comment: @Gspoon you can try it.  I haven't - I don't tend to do err.. things like herd threads:)   'there cannot be any problem' - no, I'm certainly not saying that!   It might work, it might not.

Comment: I think it is clear the order that you want things printed; the question is why does the printing have to be divided up amongst the threads?  That's what @ThingyWotsit means by "change your design": get the results you want by structuring your code differently.

Comment: @Gspoon> can't you have you threads run without printing anything? Main thread just waits until they all have completed, and then prints all results itself? As you didn't give an exact quote of your assignment, we can only guess at what it actually asks and which constraints come from your own idea of solving it and can be misguided.

Comment: After a few beers last night, another possibility occured to me.  If thread 0 creates thread 1....thread [MAX-2] creates thread [MAX-1], it can join/wait on its 'higher' thread itself before doing its own print and terminating..  Then .no need for any array.  Need to prevent thread [MAX-1] trying to wait on [MAX], however :(

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. I understand what's the reasoning behind such uni task. Nice one, I appreciate it, in some wicked manner. The algorithm is simple, however if you put something like that in a solution of real life problem you would be dommed. To put it simply: all threads, after doing their main job (sorting) must wait on barrier. When all of them reach the barrier, they wait on a separate entity and you need to trigger first one, then second, then another.

So, you need to find how to implement the barrier, every thread would wait on unless the last one reach it.

And hint for triggering: you need to trigger all of them at once. But only designed one would really process, and others would go back to waiting on the entity. (edit: it could be done in a better manner, but guess it for  yourself).

Do your work, do your research, show us some code, then you will receive some more detailed help.

BTW, there was some questions regarding to conditional variables in last 24 hours here on stack overflow. Go, look for them. You can find some explanation and some ideas to use in your task.